# Check occurrence (frequency) of exact string in a column in pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

So I need to create a simple function to check a number of occurrences of specific string 'c' in a column, and then divide it by total.
Haven't work with pyodbc before and stuck in the very beginning.

```
def get_c_i(c):
    cursor.execute('select count (*) from conditions')
    total = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    print(total)
    cursor.execute('select Name from Conditions where Name LIKE c')
    freq = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    print(freq)
    cursor.close()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Work/db/eyetoai/eyetoai/database/predict.py", line 34, in <module>
    get_c_i('Fibroadenoma')
  File "F:/Work/db/eyetoai/eyetoai/database/predict.py", line 27, in get_c_i
    cursor.execute('select Name from Conditions where Name LIKE c')
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'c'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Comment: To start, I suspect that `row[4]` is not the actual name of the column in the table. If so, please [edit] your question to show the column name.

Comment: I think your query string must be `"""select Name from Conditions where Name LIKE 'c' """`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want something like this:

```python
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Conditions")
total = cursor.fetchval()
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Conditions WHERE Name=?", "c")
freq = cursor.fetchval()
print("{0} / {1} = {2}".format(freq, total, freq/total))  # check results
```

Comment: Yes, thanks!  But had to use c without a quotation mark since it's a variable. Thanks again!